# Regex expression for validating SSN with exceptions

Tags: regex

So I am trying to write a regex expression that checks a Social Security Number, and verifies that the first 3 numbers are not 000, 666, or any 900 numbers (900, 901..., 999). I am relatively new to regex, and I am having trouble understanding how to check the first 3 characters for this condition. Then check the next 2 characters cannot be 00, and the last 4 characters cannot be all the same digits. I've come up with countless attempts that didn't quite get it done. I'm not looking for a hand out answer here, but perhaps a little help understanding how this expression could work.

Comment: do you have to do it with a regex? It can be done using lookaheads, but it's complex. It would be easier to use a regexp to validate the general format, and then check the first 3 digits separately with code.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into lookaheads and lookbehinds. I guess I don't really HAVE to use regex for this. But the rest of the validation does use regex, so for the sake of consistency (and to add to my own knowledge), I was aiming to use regex to solve this.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's because you showed no attempt to solve it yourself.

Comment: I figured that's what it was, but I did say I tried countless attempts, but considering that none of them were even close to what I really need. What's the point in showing a bunch of useless solutions?

Comment: anyone can *say* they made countless attempts. You need to *show* something, so we can help you fix it, rather than just write it all for you.

Comment: Ok that's fair I guess. Moving forward I'll be sure to add my best attempt at the solution. Thank you for the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!000|666|9\d\d)\d{3}-(?!00)\d\d-(!?(.)\1{3})\d{4}$
```

The first negative lookahead disallows `000`, `666`, and `9\d\d` at the beginning.

The second negative lookahead disallows `00` as the second block of numbers.

The third negative lookahead disallowes a character followed by 3 repetitions of the same character. This prevents you from using all the same digits in the last block.

I can't think

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/EWjrc2/2)

Comment: So the lookahead here literally just makes it that simple to find the next 3 (or however many) values? I was trying to create a group like this (for the first 3 numbers).
^(000)|(666)|(9[0-9][0-9]){3}$

Comment: Yes. And since it's a negative lookahead, it rejects them.

Comment: Ok awesome, thank you for that. That allows me to work with this a little more and tweak it to what I need. I'll update here with the exact solution.

Comment: Where my understanding struggles, is with the last condition. Checking if other values match the ones ahead. I will continue to study this and research more about regex until I truly understand it. Thank you for your kindness and helpfulness Barmar!

Comment: See this tutorial on capture groups and backreferences. https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html